# how to plot a spectrogram in logarithmic scale using specshow?

Tags: python, scale, spectrogram, librosa

I am plotting a spectrogram with the code below in python by Librosa:

```
y, sr = librosa.load( file, sr=16000)
S_full, phase = librosa.magphase(librosa.stft(y, n_fft= 8192))
librosa.display.specshow(librosa.power_to_db(S_full, ref=np.max), sr= sr, x_axis='time', y_axis='log')
```

The problem that I have is I want to change the scale in time axis (now the output shows 9 minutes, but I want to change it to 24 hours), for this I know that I should change "sr" and "hop_length", then I will use this line below:

```
librosa.display.specshow(librosa.power_to_db(S_full, ref=np.max), sr= 100, x_axis='time', y_axis='log', hop_length= 34)
```

The only problem I have is when I use "sr" in specshow command then the "y_axis='log'" is not working and it shows linear scale for y axis, but I need log scale. I also tried plt.yscale ('log'), but it is not working well with this command.

Comment: Changing `sr` changes the sample rate, which changes all frequencies. It is not the right way to change the time axis scale. If you have 9 minutes of 16kHz audio, why and how do you want that to become 24 hours long?

Comment: With changing the sampling rate I make to 24 hours. Yes changing the sampling rate will change the frequencies, but this is exactly some thing I need to do. I need to change the frequency as well as the time axis scale

Comment: Ok. Can you provide an image of how the wrong output looks like?